# How to add post from one table to category in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two different tables in my database. One called 'video' and another one is 'meta'.
In the 'video' table, I have 'title' & 'content'. On my 'meta' table, I have 'cid'. So what I am trying to do is, I want to assign each 'content' (from video) to 'cid' (from meta). Please let me know if you need any further explanation of my question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by assign? Do you want to connect 2 tables by `cid`?

Comment: I mean: connect them.

Comment: and how are the two tables relate? by which columns?

Comment: then you should go for `foreign key`

Comment: create a foreign key constraint in meta on id of video and the assign each video id to the respective meta rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your Video table must have a Primary Key column, it could be called 'cid', or 'VideoID', or anything. That key field must be Unique and should be auto-incrementing, so that every new row in Video is automatically assigned a 'cid'. Then you can store that 'cid' in the Meta table and you have a relationship. You should also setup a Foreign Key relationship so that the Meta table knows that a 'cid' must match a Primary Key in the Video table.

This relationship will alloy many Meta's to relate to one Video.

Comment: How do I set up a Foreign Key ?

Comment: ALTER TABLE meta MODIFY COLUMN cid INT NOT NULL,
 ADD CONSTRAINT meta_cid_fk
 FOREIGN KEY(cid)
 REFERENCES video(cid);

Comment: I did everything that you told. One last question, How do I know if they are connected or not?

Comment: I am a MSSQL guy, so I don't know the best way. But a quick and dirty test is to INSERT a row into META, but specify a CID that DOES NOT exist in the VIDEO table. If the relationship is setup correctly you should get an error.